# How to add parentheses to (change text of) ListBox item based on condition?

Tags: c#, conditional-formatting, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm new to stackoverflow and programming for that matter. I have the following code:

```
      if (age <= 55)
       {                      
           discount = 0.00;
           optDouglas.Checked = true;
       }
       if (age > 55)
       {
           discount = 0.2 * monthlyfee;     
           optSenior.Checked = true;                    
       }

lstInfo.Items.Add(string.Format(formatline1, "Program Discount", discount.ToString("C2")));
```

I want to show the discount in parentheses in the ListBox when there is a discount and without parentheses when discount is zero. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of _formatline1_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way to do it:

```
var formatDiscount = discount != 0 ? "({0})" : "{0}";
lstInfo.Items.Add(string.Format(formatline1, "Program Discount", string.Format(formatDiscount, discount.ToString("C2"))));
```

Comment: Yep, this is more organized, I agree!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way to do it, but I think you want something like this:

```
lstInfo.Items.Add(string.Format(formatline1, "Program Discount", discount > 0 ? "(" + discount.ToString("C2") + ")" : discount.ToString("C2")));
```